# Convert varchar column to date in mysql - error 1411

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert a varchar type column with data of format '01/06/2018', into date type of same format i.e. DDMMYYYY.

I am using the following syntax:

```
UPDATE `gto_data_raw`

SET `launch_month` = str_to_date( `launch_month`, '%d-%m-%Y' )
```

However I am receiving the following error:
20:51:13    UPDATE `gto_data_raw` SET `launch_month` = str_to_date( `launch_month`, '%d-%m-%Y' )    Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '01/06/2018' for function str_to_date   0.000 sec

Comment: You should be using [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), that is `YYYY-MM-DD`, when dealing with dates in MySQL. `DD-MM-YYYY` is non-standard and can't be sorted properly.

Comment: Your format on `str_to_date` is `dd-mm-yyyy`, but error shows your passed value is in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. Change your code as `SET launch_month = str_to_date( launch_month, '%d/%m/%Y' )` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE `gto_data_raw`
SET `launch_month` = str_to_date( `launch_month`, '%d/%m/%Y' );
```

You had the issue with the separator that you used.